# Delete spaces in cell - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following string in excel:

"      163,40   3,10    1,86   163,30  163,40  167,00  163,30  435862329"

And I have no problem to split up this column into 8 individual columns - one for each block of data. But I saw that the first column - here 163.40 is truncated so it becomes 163 - that is from a float to an integer. I realized later thats because the numbers is preceeded by four spaces - "    163.40".

So my question is how to delete these four spaces - and ONLY these four first spaces.
That would solve my problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you split the string? there is a method called `trim()` which removes the spaces at the start and end of a string. after splitting the string use `trim()` method to remove the spaces.

Comment: @Tun Zarni Kyaw - thanks, but I cannot do this after splitting because then its to late i.e. the value is truncated. If I coudl do it afterwards I could delete all spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Mid function like used below for your problem.

```
Mid(text, 5, Len(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your source string is in cell A1 and you need the 8 columns data in row 2 ; please refer to below code :

```
Function SplitMyData()

Dim var As Variant

var = Split(Trim(Range("A1").Value), " ", , vbTextCompare)

For i = 0 To UBound(var)
    Cells(2, i + 1).Value = var(i)  'Pasting vals in row 2
Next

End Function
```

You can change the source and destination cell references as per your requirements. :)